# Unity under NX?

Tags: unity, nx

I've been reading about how the new Compiz-based Unity has issues with virtual box and what not.

Since NX effectively sets up a virtual interface/session, will Unity work within an NX server session?

Has anyone had any experience with this yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unity on Compiz, for Natty, is designed with 3D graphics in mind. I believe that won't work across an NX session. But you'll still be able to use the "Classic" interface, with panels top and bottom in 11.04.

Comment: There is always the possibility of Unity 2D, currently in a PPA for Natty which could work with NX... http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/unity-2d-qt-now-available-in-ppa-for.html

Comment: Just vouching for the above comment: I have had success serving up an 11.04 2-D Unity session on a 10.10 server without Unity installed.